# python limit repeating letters

Tags: python, regex, string

What would be the best way to limit repeating letters down to 1 and 2 such as:
appppppppple => aple and apple
bbbbbeeeeeer => ber, beer, bber, bbeer

Right now, I have this:

```
a = "hellllllllllooooooooooooo"
    match = re.search('(.)\\1+', a)

    if match:
        print 'found'
        print re.sub('(.)\\1+', '\\1', a)
        print re.sub('(.)\\1+', '\\1\\1', a)
    else:
        print 'not found'
```

But it only returns:

```
helo
helloo
```

How can I make it work the way I want to?

Comment: I'm no regex expert, but it occurs to me that you'd need to address each repeating letter. Right now it seems that you're addressing it as only the most recent repeating letter. Maybe something like `('(.)\\1+)*`?

Comment: I get invalid expression with: `((.)\\1+)*`

Comment: S'why I put it as a comment and not an answer :) It was mainly to exemplify theory: you need to capture each individual repeating letter; not just the last one. I do not know the syntax for that.

Comment: The problem is not the regex, but that all possible permutations of single and double repetitions have to be emitted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use REs for this. REs are good for searching, matching, and transforming, but not for *generating* strings.

We can consider a string as a vector; each letter is a dimension, and the count of repetitions is the length of a component along that dimension. Given a vector V, You want all possible vectors of the same dimension as V, such that the value of each component is 1 if the corresponding component of V is 1, or is either 1 or 2 otherwise. Based on that, here's a function that does what you want.

```
def doppelstring(s):
    letter_groups = ((val, list(group)) for val, group in itertools.groupby(s))
    max_vector = ((val, min(len(group), 2)) for val, group in letter_groups)
    vector_components = ([dim * (l + 1) for l in range(maxlen)] for dim, maxlen in max_vector)
    return [''.join(letters) for letters in itertools.product(*vector_components)]
```

Here's a more compact version that uses slicing. It may be a bit less readable, but at least it keeps within the 78-char limit:

```
def doppelstring(s):
    max_vs = (''.join(itertools.islice(g, 2)) for k, g in itertools.groupby(s))
    components = ([s[:l + 1] for l in range(len(s))] for s in max_vs)
    return [''.join(letters) for letters in itertools.product(*components)]
```

Comment: +1 for discouraging the use of regexes in this case. The case is not regular, so regular expressions are not applicable.

Comment: regexes may not be the best solution to this, but not because the problem isn't regular.  Regexes have long been able to match non-regular languages, as the backreferences like \1 here show.

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

def permute(seq):
    if len(seq) < 2:
        yield seq
    else:
        for tail in permute(seq[2:]):
            yield seq[:2] + tail
            yield seq[:2] + seq[1:2] + tail

text = "hellllllllllooooooooooooo"
seq = re.split('(.)\\1+', text)

for result in permute(seq):
    print ''.join(result)
```

Comment: senderle: true. Permute is, well, a permutation; thus memory intensive (and, on generation, computationally intensive too).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the first **non regex** way that popped into my mind

First make a generic `squeeze` function:

```
def squeeze(str, chars='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', min=1): 
    new_str = str
    for c in chars:
        new_str = new_str.replace(c*(1+min),c*min)
    if new_str != str:
        new_str = squeeze(new_str, min=min)
    return new_str

>>> squeeze('aaaabbbbcccc')
'abc'
>>> squeeze('aaaabbbbcccc', min=2)
'aabbcc'
```

Then we can write little function that will yield each 'squeezable permutation' and can be used to initialise a `set`:

```
def squeezutations(str):
    str = squeeze(str, chars=set(str), min=2)
    for j,k in ((j,k) for j in range(2,0,-1) for k in range(1,3)):
        for c in set(str):
            yield squeeze(squeeze(str, chars=c, min=k), chars=set(str)-set(c), min=j )

>>> set(squeezutations('appppppppple'))
set(['apple', 'aple'])
```